# "Fullscreen" height <textarea> in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm not the best at using CSS to solve these problems, and I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

Right now, I'm trying to build a pastebin project entirely in PHP.
The PHP part is working great but I just can't get this.

Anyway, to the point.

I have a textarea tag that I want to fill up the whole of the screen except for a drop down box and a submit button, regardless of resolution / zoom.

Here is the source code I'm currently using.

index.php: http://pastebin.com/DZJkFG0T
style.css: http://pastebin.com/mdHYG7Xi

Massive thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: better to include your css / html in your answer, or build a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).. this way it stays accessible to future visitors to the site.

Comment: Cheers! I'll note this in future @msturdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS for your problem:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
}

body {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 180%;
    margin: 10px;
}

.centre {
    text-align: center;
}

textarea {  /* position is inherited */
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;  /* Actually the height of select and input */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, the jsfiddle wth full code: http://jsfiddle.net/a3um2/

Comment: added link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make this using js/jquery.

```
$(function(){
function reSize() {
$('.textarea_class').css({'height':(($(window).height())-250)+'px'});
}
$(document).ready(reSize);
$(window).resize(reSize);
});
```

In the example above, I've stated -250px, but you should simply calculate how much space you need for your other elements.